# How to keep array content after closing while

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following select and while to fill a variable:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM agendamentos');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
print_r ($row);
}
```

As you can see everything works well, the print_r shows all the data that matches the filter.

But when I try to print the array after the while it's empty, no data, something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM agendamentos');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}
print_r ($row);
```

I'm kinda new to php so I guess I'm missing something about arrays.

Comment: Add print_r ($row) in side the while loop

Comment: What you want, that is the main function!

Comment: If `$row` were anything *but* empty, how do you think the `while` loop would ever end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array $row only in the while loop but to get it out...
will suggest you create an empty array before the loop
and push in the value of row into it and you can fetch it outside the loop by accessing the array.  Do something like this

```
 $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM agendamentos');
$row_result = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  array_push($row_result,$row);
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($row_result);
echo "</pre>";
die;
```

Comment: There you go! Got the array data outside the while, but I'm still have "Undefined index: hora" when I try to work with the data with this echo $row_result['hora'];

Comment: $row_result comes as an array of arrays. Target what you are trying to select carefully.  Analyze the array you are getting back from the var_dump to know what you are fetching..   You can also do array_value($row_result) before var_dumping. It ll help to arrange the arrays in it better

Comment: I see, but how to I get the value of 'hora'? The dump is like this. 0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'hora' => string '08:00:00.0000' (length=13)
      'paciente' => string 'ADRIANO' (length=7)
      'observacao' => string 'Agendado para 16:50' (length=19)

Comment: use this  $row_result[0]['hora'];  to get the hora for the first result.   but to get for all of them i ll suggest you do  if(isset($row_result[0])){for($i = 0; $i < size_of($row_result); $i++){echo $row_result[$i]['hora'];}}else{echo $row_result['hora'] }    ...  the if will check if the number of response you are getting back from the loop is one or greater than one

Comment: Rough, the following code has to get the entire row where hora == x, this way it seems impossible to do. if($row_result['hora'] == '08:00:00.0000') {
                    echo '<td>08:00</td>';                   
                    echo '<td>' . $row_result['paciente'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row_result['observacao'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row_result['id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>Editar</td>';
                   }

Comment: are you trying to display a table that is been filled the the information you are getting from your database ??

Comment: Yes, I am, just realized that the only way I can do that is inside the while and iterating.

Comment: Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is how a loop work, if you want to have the data after the loop ends just save it in one variable

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM agendamentos');
$result=array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$result[]=$row;
}
print_r ($result);
```

note. the output will  be array of arrays.